# Why doesn't my regular expression implementation respect time?

Tags: javascript, regex

html template starts as {@bigfoot}
after running it through my code it is {*bigfoot}

See how the second regular expression is getting done before the first? Why?

```
html = html.replace(new RegExp("{@" + prop + "}", "g"), object[prop]);
html = html.replace(new RegExp("@", "g"), "*");
```

Comment: various values, nothign crazy. name, my_address, favorite_color

Answer (score 1):

I created this: http://jsfiddle.net/kxTs5/, but I can't recreate your problem.

Then I created this http://jsfiddle.net/kxTs5/2/; that did it :o)

In the second example, `prop` mey be a typo, or something, but it refers to something that doesn't exist in the text, so there's no match, so there's no change.

I suggest you make liberal use of `console.log` to ensure that you're trying to match what you think you're matching

Comment: Thanks for the +1, but my first answer was actually incorrect. The problem is due to the fact that `prop` doesn't correspond to anything in the source text... *probably* a typo somewhere in the code.

Answer (score -1):

first expression is not correct.

curly braces are used in regexp for specifying specific repetition count on given capture pattern.

to match curly braces you should escape them.

```
html = html.replace(new RegExp("\\{@" + prop + "\\}", "g"), object[prop]);
```

Comment: wtf -3?Yes, the curly braces DO work very well. I am testing for script injection and somehow that is messing it up so I tried boiling it down the the most basic problem. -3?

Comment: The problem is you took out too much detail. Try creating an example on jsfiddle.net that has all of the variables defined and recreates the problem.

Comment: idk it, of course, works there. http://jsfiddle.net/XPM8j/

Comment: it must be because the first regular expression isn't hitting on the rows in question.